# What happens if at leaf node both classes have same number of samples?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-trees, machine-learning-model

I analyzed a small dataset which had three features, so I kept max_depth of decision tree to be 3, in doing so I found it something intresting, there was a leaf node which had number of samples of both classes to be equal and decision tree choose one class, now I am intrested to know how class is decided in such scenario, is it random or some other criteria, I have attached image to explain my scenario[image: Decision Tree Model]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an implementation detail, and I wouldn't necessarily rely on this behavior, but presently in sklearn, it will choose the "first" class.

The `predict` method calls for the probability prediction, then takes the argmax, which in case of ties takes the first one:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L403
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html